# boxplots using ggplot2 look compressed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying the following code to generate box plots, but it is not working. Can somebody help me?

```
#BOXPLOTS

getwd()
setwd("/Users/fabiano")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
cytokines_kidneys <- read_delim("Desktop/projetos_em_andamento/lesao_renal/Frontiers_revised/cytokines_kidneys.txt", delim = "\t")


cytokines_kidneys$TNF_alpha <- as.numeric(cytokines_kidneys$TNF_alpha)
class(cytokines_kidneys)
str(cytokines_kidneys)
names(cytokines_kidneys) <- c("GROUP", "TNF_alpha", "IL1beta", "IL6")


cytokines_kidneys$GROUP<-factor(cytokines_kidneys$GROUP, 
levels=c("KO sepsis", "WT sepsis", "KO rhabdo", "WT rhabdo", "KO control", "WT control"))

ggplot(cytokines_kidneys) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = GROUP, y = "TNF_alpha"), outlier.shape = NA) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, angle = 0), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size =22, angle = 0),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 0, angle = 0)) 
+ ylab("TNF alpha") + coord_flip()
```

[image: figure]

thank you very much, Fabiano

Comment: What if you replace `y = "TNF_alpha"` with `y = TNF_alpha` ?

Comment: worked!!! can you explain me the rationale?

Comment: Inside the ggplot function, `TNF_alpha` is the variable and thus the values of the variable, while "TNF_alpha" is just a string.